# How do I wire my new fixture with fewer wires than the old fixture?

Tags: wiring, led

This is the original fixture. The new fixture has the standard white,black, and green wires.

[image]

Comment: You've got three good answers so I won't add another one. I will however compliment you on taking a picture before disconnecting the fixture

Answer (score 3):

Just connect all blacks together, all whites together and all grounds together.  Can use wire nuts or other type of wire connectors allowed in your local.

What you are showing is a fixture in the middle of a circuit, power comes in on one cable and goes out the other.  It is using the light fixture as a wire connector, but only good for two wires(2 blacks on half).

For more than two wires you need to use separate wire connectors, wire nuts, wago.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

Answer (score 3):

After turning off the power at the breaker (confirm it's off by leaving the light on - make sure it goes off when you flip the breaker).

- You will need 3 wire nuts (this appears to be a simple US-spec lamp base).
- Unscrew all 4 wires from the lamp base.
- Snip off the shepherd's hooks bent into the ends of the wires.
- Strip each of the wires back about 1/2" to give a nice, straight end.
- Wire nut the two white wires to the white wire of your new fixture.
- Wire nut the two black wires to the black wire of your new fixture.
- Wire nut the bare copper wire to the green wire of your new fixture.
- Mount the new fixture to the box.
- Turn the power back on.
- Enjoy!

Comment: You're welcome, @Adman. You've taken the [tour], so you should be familiar with the proper way of saying "thanks" around here.

Answer (score 2):

You have two cables. One is from the switch or a previous fixture. The other goes on to the next fixture. There are three possible fixture configurations:

- Double Screws - That's your old fixture, and we know the new fixture is not like that.
- Wires - Connect the all three black wires together with a wire nut and all three white wires together with a wire nut.
- Single Screws - Identify which is hot and which is neutral, add a short black wire to the hot screw and a short white wire to the neutral screw. Then connect all three black wires together with a wire nut and all three white wires together with a wire nut.

If this is a 15A circuit then you can use 12 AWG or 14 AWG wire. If this is a 20A circuit then you must use 12 AWG (or larger, but 12 AWG is standard) wire. You can use individual wires or you can take a piece of NM cable and strip the outer sheath to get black and white wires for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!